# how do I register multiple interface implementations with multiple keys in castle windsor?

Tags: c#-4.0, castle-windsor

I have a validation interface like so:

```
public interface IValidation<T> {
  bool IsValid(T item, ref AggregateException fail);
}
```

I have a file importer that needs several validation interfaces

```
public FileImporter {
  IEnumerable<IValidation<Patient>> Validators { get; set; }

  public FileImporter(IWindsorContainer container) {
    // the ResolveAll method does not do this
    Validators = container.ResolveAll<IValidation<Patient>>("fileValidation");
  }
}
```

I also have another class that has more validators but uses some of the same ones used in `FileImporter`.

```
public PatientService {
  IEnumerable<IValidation<Patient>> Validators { get; set; }

  public PatientService(IWindsorContainer container) {
    // the ResolveAll method does not do this
    Validators = container.ResolveAll<IValidation<Patient>>("userInputValidation");
  }
}
```

For example I have two validators `LastNameValidator` and `DateOfBirthValidator`. `LastNameValidator is used in both the`FileImporter`and the`PatientService`.`DateOfBirthValidator`is only used in the`PatientService` class. The implementation of these two classes are below the question.

**My question is how can i wire up these two classes so that they are used as described above. And what method call should I make to resolve them?**

```
public class LastNameValidator : IValidation<Patient> {
  public bool IsValid(Patient p, ref AggregateException fail) {
    var isValid = !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(p.LastName))
    if (!isValid)
        // update fail
    return isValid;
  }
}

public class DateOfBirthValidator : IValidation<Patient> {
  public bool IsValid(Patient p, ref AggregateException fail) {

    if (!p.DateOfBirth.HasValue) {
        // update fail, can't be empty
        return false;
    }
    if (p.DateOfBirth.Value > DateTime.Now) {
        // update fail, can't be in future
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider the [Typed Factory Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility.ashx).  You could register your validators with the names "lastnamevalidator" and "dobvalidator".  Then create a factory interface for grabbing those specific validators.  You just need the interface -- the facility will do the implementation:

```
public interface IValidatorFactory
{
    IValidator GetLastNameValidator();
    IValidator GetDobValidator();
}
```

Now pass the IValidatorFactory to your component.  This also removes the need to pass the Windsor container around (which isn't a good idea as it tightly couples your code to Windsor and makes unit testing more difficult).

Now just call the factory methods to access the particular validator each component needs.

**UPDATE:**

Still not clear on which part of your system is going to determine which IValidators to use, but maybe this would work.  Use a marker inteface that is based on `IValidator`.

```
public interface IFileValidator : IValidator
{
}

public interface IUserInputValidator : IValidator
{
}
```

Now have your validators implement the marker interfaces depending on where they are going to be used -- and remember you can implement multiple interfaces so validators can be used in multiple situations.  Example:

```
public class FileValidator : IFileValidator
{
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public class DobValidator : IUserInputValidator, IFileValidator
{
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public class LastNameValidator : IUserInputValidator
{
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Change the factory interface to return just the specific types of validators:

```
public interface IValidatorFactory
{
    IFileValidator[] GetFileValidators();
    IUserInputValidator[] GetUserInputValidators();
}
```

Now register the validators accorindg to their "type".  If a validator has multiple uses, make sure to add a `.Forward<>` defintion for Windsor:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
container.Register(
    Component.For<IValidatorFactory>().AsFactory(),

    Component.For<IFileValidator>().ImplementedBy<FileValidator>(),
    Component.For<IUserInputValidator>().ImplementedBy<LastNameValidator>(),
    Component.For<IFileValidator>().Forward<IUserInputValidator>().ImplementedBy<DobValidator>()
    );
```

Comment: I understand that I shouldn't be passing in the container. I plan on doing constructor injection. But for my problem, it was the only way I could think of to show my problem. The code needing the validators does not know which ones it needs. I can't use `CollectionResolver` because it will simply give me all of the validators for both `FileImporter` and `PatientService`

Comment: So each component will know which *type* of validator it needs, correct?  It won't know how many "file validators" there are, but it will know the *type* or *classification* of validator?

Comment: See my update.  I'm still not clear on how your system is going to decide which validators to use.  I took a guess that a marker interface might work.

Comment: I was really hoping to avoid marker interfaces, but after having done some research on my own, this seems to be the easiest solution.

Comment: Yeah I'd rather use attributes than marker interfaces, but I don't see an easy way to perform this type of solution in Windsor based on attributes instead of types.